# Is it possible to write data into input device? tried to write in data to HID input device retrun -1, but manufacturer app can write in

Tags: wireshark, hid, python-3.10

I am trying to send data to Hid device which don't have api for me to use, but they have an application, I use wireshark to captured their data and tried to send the same data using my code. I am using Windows 10 python 3.10.5 and hidapi, I can get the information of the device and read properly, but when I write it return -1 to me and wireshark didn't capture any packet.I am guessing  that it is decause the device is input device, what I am curious is how can the application send data to input device and how can I achieve it. The picture below is what I captured  while using their application, I search some post on web and tried some other python hid modules, but their are even more problem so I think I might stick on hidapi.
[image]

```
import hid
import time


data_2_list=[]
data=[0x80,0x07,0x05,0x05,0x00,0xb7,0x02,0x00,0x01,0x07,0x4b,0x09,0x64,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x5b,0x2f,0x58,0x77,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x50,0xf0,0x26,0x0f,0x00,0x90,0x2f,0x03,0x50,0x03,0x03,0x0f,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x4b,0x09,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x4b,0x09]
i=0
line=0
try:
    print("open device")
    h=hid.device()
    h.open(0x047A,0x1004) #vendor ID,product ID
    print(h.get_manufacturer_string())
    print(h.get_product_string())
    
    
    h.set_nonblocking(1)
    print("write the data")
    print(h.write(data))

except IOError as ex:
    print(ex)
```

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer may be using feature reports to send data to the device. Is there a there a "send feature report" function that you can try?

Comment: @aja I tried 'send_feature_report()' function in hidapi, still got -1 as return wireshark shows that I didn't send any package. Is there any other posibility?